# AWS S3 Signed URL Upload 403 Over Certain Limit

Tags: amazon-s3, next.js, vercel, pre-signed-url

I'm using a signed url to upload to a AWS S3 bucket with my client, which is deployed on Vercel

**Problem:**

File uploading is ***working for anything under 12 MB***. Whenever I try to upload a file over 12 MB I get a 403 Forbidden.

Locally I can upload files larger than 12MB. It's only a problem when it's deployed to Vercel.

It's not a timeout because it occurs after only a few seconds.

**Endpoint to generate the signedURL**

```
    const AWS = require('aws-sdk');

AWS.config.update({
    accessKeyId: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID,
    secretAccessKey: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY,
    region: 'us-east-2',
});

const s3 = new aws.S3();

export default async function handler(req, res) {
    if (req.method === 'POST') {
        const { fileName, fileType, filePath, fileId } = req.body;

        // Ensure inputs are provided
        if (!fileName || !fileType) {
            return res.status(400).json({ error: 'File name and type are required' });
        }

        const s3Params = {
            Bucket: 'test-bucket',
            Key: `${filePath}/${fileId}-${fileName}`,
            Expires: 1000,
            ContentType: fileType,
            ACL: 'private',
        };

        // Generate the pre-signed URL
        s3.getSignedUrl('putObject', s3Params, (err, data) => {
            if (err) {
                return res.status(500).json({ error: 'Failed to generate a pre-signed URL', details: err.message });
            }
            return res.status(200).json({ signedRequest: data });
        });
    } else {
        res.setHeader('Allow', ['POST']);
        res.status(405).end(`Method ${req.method} Not Allowed`);
    }
}
```

**Here is my code to upload (handles multiple uploads at one time):**

```
    const handleFilesChange = async (e) => {
    const files = Array.from(e.target.files);

    files.forEach(async (file) => {
        try {
            const fileId = uuidv4();
            // Request a pre-signed URL from your server
            const response = await axios.post('/api/s3-signature', {
                fileName: file.name,
                fileType: file.type,
                fileId: fileId,
                filePath: 'test-folder',
            });

            const signedRequest = response.data.signedRequest;

            // Upload the file directly to S3 using the pre-signed URL
            await axios.put(signedRequest, file, {
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': file.type,
                },
                timeout: 60000,
                onUploadProgress: (progressEvent) => {
                    const percentCompleted = Math.round((progressEvent.loaded * 100) / progressEvent.total);
                    setFileProgress((prevState) => ({
                        ...prevState,
                        [file.name]: {
                            progress: percentCompleted,
                            type: file.type === 'application/pdf' ? 'pdf' : 'image',
                            size: file.size,
                        },
                    }));
                },
            });
        } catch (error) {
            console.log({ error });
        }
    });
};
```

Comment: Are you using Serverless function or Edge function?

Comment: Serverless with Next.js `_api` folder. But that's just to generate the signed url because Vercel has a 4.5 MB limit for serverless functions